# Mixing Swift and Obj-C inside framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, bridging-header

How can I use non public swift classes if I have an Objective C framework, not app. For introducing swift code in a objective C project I follow this steps:

- Create swift file and not create a bridging header because using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported.
- Create a swift simple class. The class inherit from NSObject and has @objc tag.
- Enable the following configurations:

  - Defines Module : YES
  - Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries : YES
  - Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
- Import the umbrella file ("ModuleName-Swift.h") where you want to use
  the swift class.
- If the swift classes are public it works but this classes are
  accessible from outside, for example the app that uses the framework.
- **If the swift classes are non public they aren't accessible in the
  objective-c files in the framework.**

The solution for this problem if the project is an app and not a framework is creating a bridging header. I'm searching for a solution for this problem for a framework.